# When is region.tpl.php used?

Tags: 7, theming

I've got a Drupal 7 site, and I'm working with regions. It seems that no matter what theme I use, `/modules/system/region.tpl.php` will never be used / applied. It seems that any `hook_preprocess_region` will not be invoked either.

Is there anything particular about hooking into how regions are themed?

Comment: Is your theme rendering the regions?

Comment: Quite likely, that the themes you used have their own version (override) for this template. So you need to add some more information to your question: Where and how did you implement the hook? Probably also add some information about what you want to do and how you did it so far. This would give us a better base to telling you what went wrong.